# How to find a specific css value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve and store in a variable a specific CSS rule of an element

```
<div class="stuff" style="left: 50px"></div>
```

Im trying to get it with jQuery and store it in a var but its not working

```
 var leftStuff = $('.stuff').attr('left').val();
 alert(leftStuff);
```

What I am hoping to achieve is to get the alery to say `(50)`

Comment: keep in mind, the ".stuff" selector is selecting the "div" control, which does not have a "left" attribute, but has a "style" attribute (containing a "left" property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
var leftStuff = $('.stuff').css('left');
```

Answer (score 3):

If your actually looking to get the left offset your could use

```
var offsetL = $('.stuff').offset().x;
```

Answer (score 2):

use `.css('left')` to get css property left value:

```
 var leftStuff = $('.stuff').css('left');
 alert(leftStuff);
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvLxt/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
var leftStuff = $('.stuff').css('left');
```

That should work!

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** method to get CSS property

```
var leftStuff = $('.stuff').css('left');
alert(leftStuff);
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/z8Lkd/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

hej,

the store new inline styles you have to use this syntax

```
$('.stuff').attr("style", "color: '#CCC'; width: '500px'");
```

To get the value as a string

```
var leftStuff = $('.stuff').attr('style');
```

Comment: not exactly what im looking for, only looking to callback the value of left